# C#: Xamarin.Android main.axml replaced by activity_main.axml and content_main.axml

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

[image]

Hi. First of all, I want to say I am totally new to Xamarin.Android using Visual Studio, so my question may be very silly to most of you here. But I'm just so confused with all the tutorials I'm following and the actual project structure that I have on my VS version which is 15.7.4.

Anyway, on all of the tutorial I'm following, their layout folder contains only one layout file which is main.axml. In my case, let's say I create a blank android app, mine would contain activity_main.axml. When I create for example a Single View app, mine would contain activity_main.axml and content_main.axml.

I am not sure if this is the new android structure but I'm really having a problem following along the tutorials because I have a totally different layout structure. I tried searching for other tutorials but all of them use main.axml.

Now let's say activity_main and content_main are the new layout structure:

1. If I create a blank app, should I create a new layout file and render it via activity_main?
2. If I'm creating a multi-screen app, how do I add a new activity and call/render it via trigger like a button click? Would it be the same thing as with main.axml?
3. What's the importance of content_main? Am I good without this layout file?

I am really confused right now, and any help I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: You can make use of fragments and can render them in your main.axml content view,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The activity_main.xaml file will render when you start this app. You don't need to create a new layout if you don't want to.
2. To navigate to another activity via something like a button click will require use of an Intent that is called when you raise a relevant click event, so I would look this up in the docs.
3. The default content_main in the Single View app template is just a view nested in activity_main that renders "Hello World!" if I recall correctly. You don't need it, no.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot @uprightbassfan78 ! After checking the initial codes, I just realized earlier today that I can treat activity_main.axml the sames as main.axml and dont need to bother too much with content_main. I wasn't sure at first though but thank you for confirming!